# Generate an xml schema from a variable (like a here-string)

Tags: xml, powershell, schema, xsd-validation

Ultimately, I'm wondering if it's possible to validate an Xml file against a schema that's contained in a here-string variable (rather than an already-existing .xsd file).

- I've found several examples online and have read through much of the [[System.Xml.Schema]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema?view=netframework-4.8) documentation and can find numerous examples of how to create an Xml schema from an .xml file (or use an already-existing .xsd file), but I can't find anything about generating and using a schema that's contained in a here-string variable.
- None of the (seemingly) applicable classes I've come across (XmlReader, XmlTextReader, XmlSchema, etc) have a constructor or method overload that works similar to [XmlDocument.LoadXml(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml?view=netframework-4.8#system-xml-xmldocument-loadxml(system-string)), which can accept a here-string containing Xml.

Am I missing something, or am I stuck with having to create an .xsd file if I want to validate an XmlDocument instance against a schema?

- My concern with creating an .xsd file (in the environment I'm working with) is that write permissions to XYZ folder have the potential to be denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschema?view=netframework-4.8) has a [Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.read?view=netframework-4.8#system-xml-schema-xmlschema-read(system-io-textreader-system-xml-schema-validationeventhandler)) method that allows you to take input from a [System.IO.TextReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textreader?view=netframework-4.8), and therefore from a [System.IO.StringReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader?view=netframework-4.8), and therefore from a [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8).

```
$xmlSchemaText = @"
<schema xml here>
"@

$stringReader = [System.IO.StringReader]::new($xmlSchemaText)

$xmlSchema = [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema]::Read($stringReader)
```

Comment: Note, of course, that it becomes a lot more difficult (but not impossible) if the schema is made up of several different schema documents linked by `xs:include` or `xs:import` declarations.